# Lookup django model using two or more different keys

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

First time developing a django application, and am trying to do something somewhat non-standard...

Is there a way to configure a view that will allow a user to look up a certain model by either one of two unique model attributes.

Ideally, both of these URL schemes would be possible

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('api/somemodel/<int:model_id>/', views.SomeModelDetailView.as_view())
   path('api/somemodel/<str:model_name>/', views.SomeModelDetailView.as_view())
]
```

A simplified example model... Both the id and the name are guaranteed to be unique. Also, by convention, my data is entered in such a way that a name will always be a string and never an integer

```
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Currently, I have this working with the following view...

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import status           
from rest_framework.response import Response

from . import models

class SomeModelDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):                                                                                                                                                                       
    queryset = models.SomeModel.objects.all()                                                                             
    serializer_class = serializers.SomeModelSerializer                                                                    

    def get(self, request, model_name=None, model_id=None, format=None):                                            

        field = None                                                                                                    
        key = None                                                                                                      
        try:                                                                                                            
            if model_id:                                                                                              
                field = "model_id"                                                                                    
                key = model_id
                m = models.SomeModel.objects.get(id=model_id)                                                     
            elif model_name:                                                                                          
                field = "model_name"                                                                                  
                key = model_name
                m = models.SomeModel.objects.get(name=model_name)                                                 
            else:                                                                                                       
                return Response("Neither model_id nor model_name were provided", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except models.SomeModel.DoesNotExist:                                                                             
            return Response("Unknown {field}: {key}".format(field=field, key=key), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)  

        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()                                                                  
        serializer = serializer_class(m)                                                                          

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

However, I am wondering if there is a better way that fits more into a `ViewSet`/`Router` (or other) `DRF` mechanic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both existing answers (Don's and changak's) are very informative... however I wanted to take it a step further.

This is what I ended up with - it is inspired from Changak's answer however is slightly more generic

```
class MultiKeyGetObject(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'lookup_fields'):
            raise AssertionError("Expected view {} to have `.lookup_fields` attribute".format(self.__class__.__name__))

    def get_object(self):
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if field in self.kwargs:
                self.lookup_field = field
                break
        else:
            raise AssertionError(
                'Expected view %s to be called with one of the lookup_fields: %s' %
                (self.__class__.__name__, self.lookup_fields))

        return super().get_object()
```

I also loved learning about `Q` objects from Don - I can imagine a use case where you would want to retrieve objects using ALL of the lookup fields (either an AND or an OR). I feel this is getting into filter territory, however it may be useful...

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404

    def get_object(self):
        query = reduce(or_, [Q(**{field: self.kwargs[field]}) for field in self.lookup_fields if field in self.kwargs])

        obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), query)

        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj
```

Both of the above methods can then be used by a view such as...

```
class SomeObjectDetailAPIView(MultiKeyGetObject, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.SomeModelSerializer                                 
    queryset = models.SomeModel.objects.all()                                          
    lookup_fields = ('id', 'name')
```

Comment: I like this solution, I wasn't considering making it work better in DRF

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do that in a generic way, first change the urlpttern to this:

```
   urlpatterns = [
   path('api/somemodel/<str:pk>/', views.SomeModelDetailView.as_view()),
] ### this path matches both of the keys you wanted str and integer(integer is a str too)
```

then in the view you only need to override the get_object() in this way(don't override `get()` that is not the drf way):

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import status           
from rest_framework.response import Response

from . import models

class SomeModelDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):                                                                                                                                                                       
    queryset = models.SomeModel.objects.all()                                                                             
    serializer_class = serializers.SomeModelSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs[self.lookup_url_kwarg] ## first get value the url parameter(pk)

        ### then here convert its type to int if it's an integer,
        ### it's not a bad thing, path() will have done this if we specify its type `int` in the url

        try:
            self.kwargs[self.lookup_url_kwarg] = int(pk)
            self.lookup_field = 'id' ### change the lookup field to 'id' if it's an integer
        except:
            self.lookup_field = 'name' ### change the lookup field to 'name' if it's a str

        return super(SomeModelDetailView, self).get_object() ## finally call the super get_object
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using what Django calls "Q objects". These allow you to perform logical operations to queries allowing you to query for `id=model_id` or `name=model_name`.

For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
m = models.SomeModel.objects.get(Q(id=model_id) | Q(name=model_name))
...
```